# Difference between uppercase and titlecase

Tags: java, unicode, title-case

**What's the difference between `uppercase` and `titlecase`.**
Frankly, I never heard of `titlecase` before.

In java there are seperate methods for both:

- `Character.isTitleCase(char)`
- `Character.isUpperCase(char)`

Some websites define it as follows:

> **TitleCase:** Matches characters **that combine an uppercase letter with a lowercase letter**, such as Nj and Dz

But there must be more to it: the `isTitleCase(char)` method only accepts 1 character. So - if this was the case - then this method would need at least 2 characters.

Comment: What has the title to do with the question?

Comment: my mistake, was making 2 questions at the same time. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String capitalize - better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536277/string-capitalize-better-way)

Comment: [Confusing ToUpper and ToTitle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18559587/995714)

Comment: Note that e.g. Croatian U+01C4 to U+01CC `Ǆ`,`ǅ`,`ǆ`,`Ǉ`,`ǈ`,`ǉ`,`Ǌ`,`ǋ`,`ǌ` are *single characters*, now compare `Ǌ` and `ǋ`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It accepts only one *Unicode* character. It turns out that [Ǆ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1c4/index.htm) actually **is** only one character: look how it shows in monospaced font: `Ǆ`. The titlecase version is [ǅ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c5/index.htm) and a lowercase version [ǆ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c6/index.htm) exists as well.

Comment: wow, I had no idea! I guess this is something that is used in specific languages ? (not in English or French right ?)

Comment: The closest situation I can think of is œ and æ, but they behave differently: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0153/index.htm

Comment: @bvdb The reason this happens is for round-trip compatibility with legacy encodings in which such things occurred.  For example, in the MacRoman encoding, byte 0xDE  maps to U+FB01 `LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI` (so a **ﬁ** character) and byte 0xDF  maps to  U+FB02   `LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FL` (a  **ﬂ** character). Round-trip guarantees allow you to losslessly convert from MacRoman to Unicode and back to MacRoman again without anything changing.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's already been answered before but I'm just adding a really quick breakdown:

Combined characters:

- Ǆ = Uppercase Only
- ǆ = Lowercase Only
- ǅ = Titlecase Only

Single characters:

- D = Uppercase AND Titlecase
- d = Lowercase Only

Answer (score 3):

WHAT IS TITLECASE:

- in some languages and scripts, there are digraph letters - i.e. a single Unicode code point which is a combination of 2 human-readable characters, displayed as a kind of a combination glyph.
- only digraphs can be titlecase - i.e. the lowercase digraph of "dz" corresponds to uppercase "DZ" and titlecase "Dz".
- so, "UPPERCASE", "Titlecase" and "lowercase"

> It accepts only one Unicode character.

Not exactly correct.

Greek language has lots of titlecase glyphs, and there are also more Latin titlecases then "DZ".

To view all titlecase characters in the world, start Excel (or the free Power BI Desktop app), then Data/Get Data/Blank Query, and execute the following Power Query M language query by copy-pasting it to Query/Advanced Editor:

```
let
 downloaded = Web.Contents("https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt"),
 csv = Csv.Document(downloaded,
                    [Delimiter=";",
                      Encoding=65001, // UTF-8
                      QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None // allow line breaks within the quoted string
                    ]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(csv,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Column1", "Character code"}, {"Column2", "Character name"}, {"Column3", "Category"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Glyph", each Character.FromNumber(Expression.Evaluate("0x" & [Character code]))),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Character code", "Glyph", "Character name", "Category"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [Category] = "Lt")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: what is the titlecase of 'ij'?

Comment: @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ, any case of "ij" does not exist as a single Unicode character. You could just type it as 2 separate characters "Ij" for the desired effect but only the single letter "I" can be considered titlecase, not "Ij" combined because they're 2 seperate characters.