# Why toTitle does not capitalize a lower cased word in Go?

Tags: python, go, capitalize

I need to implement the capitalize method of python in Go. I know that first I have to lowercase it and then use `toTitle` on it. Have a look at the sample code :

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "ALIREZA"
    loweredVal:=strings.ToLower(s)
    fmt.Println("loweredVal:", loweredVal)
    toTitle := strings.ToTitle(loweredVal)
    fmt.Println("toTitle:", toTitle)
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559587/confusing-toupper-and-totitle

Comment: And what's the question? Anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the `capitalize()` method converts the first character of a string to capital (uppercase) letter.

If you are seeking to do the same with Go, you can range over the string contents, then leverage the `unicode` package method [ToUpper](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#ToUpper) to convert the first rune in the string to uppercase, then cast it to a string, then concatenate that with the rest of the original string.

example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    s := "ALIREZA foo bar"
    loweredVal := strings.ToLower(s)
    fmt.Println("loweredVal:", loweredVal)
    toTitle := capFirstChar(loweredVal)
    fmt.Println("toTitle:", toTitle)
}

func capFirstChar(s string) string {
    for index, value := range s {
        return string(unicode.ToUpper(value)) + s[index+1:]
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: `Title()` does not capitalize the first letter of a string--it capitalizes the first letter of each word.

Comment: Good point, it was fine for the sake of his example but would fail in other cases with multi-word strings. Thanks, edited

Comment: The Title method from the strings package has been deprecated.